# Creating a jar file after doing some modifications to it

Tags: jar

I have downloaded bouncycastle.jar file changed the X509Util.class from private to public 
now i want to recerate the jar again how can ito recreate the jar.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how complicated it is. In most cases you can just rezip everything and rename the zip file extension to `.jar`. Be sure to include the manifest file first if there is one. The JDK also provides a command line tool for creating jar files.

If the code being modified was signed, then recreating the jar with signatures will obviously be impossible.