# How can React-Native textInput component can be modified?

Tags: android, react-native

React-native offers developing native modules and UI components in [its official site](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content).

However I want to make minor changes in the [`TextInput` component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput) which is used in my app and is found on my computer. However there is no a Java file that is related with `TextInput`.

Is there any way to make small changes in `TextInput` in my app?

Comment: what do you want to change in the `TextInput` component?

Comment: If you want to make small changes (don't exactly know what this means), you can always extend TextInput in RN and make those changes.

Comment: @AakashSigdel I've explained here; https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6263

Comment: @zvona is really a small change. But I want to try in my own app. If it works I can PR for that change in React-Native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply changes to React Native android source and have them in the app, you have to **compile it from source**.

You can follow the official guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html#content

Comment: Says that `You will need to build React Native from source if you want to work on a new feature/bug fix...` - quasi I read this yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

**Since RN v0.21.0**

The distribution of Android files have changed and is now done with npm.

The files can be found under `node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.21.0/`in a the archive `react-native-0.21.0-sources.jar`

They can't be changed just like this, thought you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533224/how-to-modify-a-java-file-in-jar-file)

**Edit** : Works with RN 0.20.0 or lower

I guess what you're looking for is this [file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/d3f2081d9091179ed0ac6511c6c660947b950e45/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputManager.java)

You can modify it in your react-native folder under node_modules :

`node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/`

Comment: I've initialized a new project. However there is no `node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid` folder. Do you have it?

Comment: What is your version of react-native ?

Comment: v 0.21 - I upgraded it yesterday.   `  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.21.0"...`

Comment: Indeed, I was on 0.20.0 and the structure has changed since. I'll have another look and let you know if I find out anything.

Comment: OK, everything is now loaded with npm and can be found here : `node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.21.0/`. But it's a .jar file meaning it's not that easy to change it. You'd rather write your own component and adapt to to your needs. Or try and get your modification integrated in RN by submitting it [here](https://productpains.com)

Comment: Yes. Actually I saw that today when I was researching. Do you have an idea how can I change now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105286/discussion-between-g-hamaide-and-user3765109).

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm trying to find how can I change. If I can found, will write here..

Comment: I should be change in a different way. Although I remove node_modules/react-native/android folder, everything works normally. FYI.